# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{a_{n+1}} - \frac{1}{a_n})$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, summation

Let $(a_n)_n$ be a sequence, in which $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n = \infty$. Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{a_{n+1}} - \frac{1}{a_n})$ converges.

I tried to use the Cauchy Criterion but couldn't conclude anything. Can someone help?

Comment: It telescopes..

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{a_{n+1}}-\frac1{a_n}\right)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\frac1{a_{n+1}}-\frac1{a_n}\right)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac1{a_{N+1}}-\frac1{a_1}=-\frac1{a_1}$$

Comment: Oh yes, I feel so dumb.. haha. Thanks man

Answer (score 7):

Notice $\sum\limits_{n=1}^m (\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{a_n})=\frac{1}{a_{m+1}}-\frac{1}{a_1}$ and clearly $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty} \frac{1}{a_m+1}-\frac{1}{a_1}=-\frac{1}{a_1}$ since $\lim\limits_{m\to \infty} a_m=\infty$